# how to get result from node.js in knockout observablearray

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, knockout.js

this is my node.js code :

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
var MovieDB = require('moviedb')('API KEY');
MovieDB.searchMovie({ query: 'Alien' }, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

here in res, i got result, my problem is, i want to store this res in knockout observablearray and display to html page, how could i do that?

i am not able to find any links where they explained to write knockout viewmodel with node.js code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an observableArray, something similar to this -

`self.movies = ko.observableArray()`

and if you get collection of objects from server, assign it using following syntax -

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
var MovieDB = require('moviedb')('API KEY');
MovieDB.searchMovie({ query: 'Alien' }, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    self.movies(res); //setter;
});
```